# Mypy can't find submodule

Tags: python, mypy, python-3.8

I'm trying to help mypy to find correct paths for modules but I don't understand hwo to do it from docs https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
I added stubs by `stubgen *.py` but still the same. I read that I also have to create `py.typed` file but i don't know how to generate it? Is there a way to make it more simple?

File structure:

```
├── mod
│   └── y.py
└── x.py
```

Error:

```
x.py:1: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'mod.y'
```

Comment: Add a `mod/__init__.py`, or if `mod` should be a namespace package, a `mod/__init__.pyi`.

Comment: thanks :) It works.